# Make the image take the full height/width of the div while preserving the aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making a simple lightbox for an image gallery. Problem is that the image does not take the full height/width of the `#wrapper` div.

I tried using `max-width` and `max-height` css properties, but the image does not take the full width/height. In a small screen the image takes the full height/width accordingly, but in a large screen width, it does not take the full width/height.

Also tried `width:100%; height:auto;` but if the height of the image is large it just overlaps the `#wrapper` div.

Demo at [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/BjNebZ).

html:

```
<div id="snap-modal">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x450">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#snap-modal {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  outline: 1px solid lightgrey;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#snap-modal #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#snap-modal #wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

How do I make an image take the full height/width depending on the image size inside a div (in css if possible) while preserving the aspect ratio? Thank you.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVJZVW

Comment: @yjs Sorry, but I want to preserve the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible try `object-fit: cover;` propery along with height or width

```
#snap-modal #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

check for more details https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: This is not working. The image is not taking the full width/height of the `#wrapper` div. Could you maybe try in the codepen first. Plus I want it to work in maximum browser.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any good answer, so I am using js to do that.

```
var image;
var container = snap_modal.find('#wrapper');
var snap_image = container.find('img');

function change_image() {
    snap_image.attr('src', image.attr('src'));
    image_title.text(image.attr('alt'));
}

function resize_snap() {
    change_image();
    snap_image.css({
        'height': container.height(),
        'width': 'auto'
    })
    if (snap_image.width() > container.width()) {
        snap_image.css({
            'width': container.width(),
            'height': 'auto'
        })
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#snap-list .snap img').on('click', function () {
        image = $(this);
        resize_snap();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resize_snap();
    });
})
```

This is not the finest work, but hope this will help someone like me.

Answer (score 0):

i have update the snippet with the large image but result is same image sizr is now 1920x1200

```
#snap-modal #wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;// remove this line with widht:100%
  max-height: 100%;// remove this line with height:100%
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
#snap-modal {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  outline: 1px solid lightgrey;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}

#snap-modal #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; 
}

#snap-modal #wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="snap-modal">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/434976-happy-valentines-day-timeline-cover.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish to preserve the aspect ratio of the image. With the image `width:100%; height:100%;`, it lose its aspect ratio.

Comment: then use only with attribute  the height will be scaled

Comment: check now i have remove height from #wrapper and from img now image height will be scaled down or up with aspect ratio

Comment: It does not work, or at least to what I am expecting it to be. You could try the same in my [codepen](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/BjNebZ) with your code and check it out. It overlaps the `#wrapper` div.

Comment: the area is smaller then image required #snap-modal has also height attribute

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `.max-width` property to `100%` which is not beneficial in this case, since you want to force the width of the image to be equal to that of the container(`#wrapper`), you must use property `min-width: 100%` instead, this will force the image to take complete container width. So the css now becomes:

```
#snap-modal #wrapper img {
  min-width: 100%; // This is updated style
  min-height: 100%; //Similarly for height
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

See the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGVKEV)

Comment: The image overlaps the div. I want the image to be contained inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps:

```
#snap-modal {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  outline: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

#snap-modal #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#snap-modal #wrapper img {
  margin:auto;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I wish to preserve the aspect ratio of the image. With the image `width:100%; height:100%;`, it lose its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Hey visit the link was very helpful for me 
[maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design](http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/)